# Can I run a WinForms app from the Task Scheduler and have it press a button?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, winforms

I'm on Win7. I've a small program (that I didn't write) which contains a single button. I need this to be run on a schedule and the button pressed (the app can then be closed).

I have set up the Task Scheduler on my Win7 machine so it runs the app, but I cannot see any way of getting the button pressed. As far as I can tell the app has no command-line arguments.

Is there a way of getting the scheduler to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) should be able to do that. With AutoHotkey, you can create your script and then use Task Scheduler to run the script.